# how can i translate JSON RPC API for curl into a http://..... address

Tags: json-rpc

I have access to a private chain Ethereum node that is accessible via http https://sustainability-chain.info (e.g. i can access it with metamask using special RPC and networkid 20030117

Based on https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_blocknumber I would like to change

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1}' sustainability-chain.info
```

which actually works better using:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1}' sustainability-chain.info
```

into something like:

```
https://sustainability-chain.info/?method=eth_blockNumber&params=[]&id=1
```

but that does not work

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need a server that accepts input in your desired syntax and make a translation to the RPC syntax accepted by geth, and to return the result. I don't know a product that does that automatically.

Comment: thank you. I installed web3 and access the information with java-scripts now

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","id":1}' https://sustainability-chain.info
```

Comment: the curl works fine, but i wonder if I can translate that into a http://sustainability-chain.info/application/json?method=eth_blocknumber&id=1 or similar address in a browser and if I can how do i need to to do this.